# Mule ConsumerIterator error is LinkedHashMap

Tags: mule

I have a flow which queries SalesForce. The query is wrapped in an enricher. Here is the flow.

```
     <flow name="ProcessEmployee"> 
            <enricher doc:name="Message Enricher" target="#
                                             [variable:IDRec]">
                <sfdc:query config-ref="Salesforce_Config"
                    doc:name="Check if Employee Id exists"

          query="select id from employee where

          deptId='#[payload[&quot;deptId&quot;]]'   &amp;&amp; 
                       empId='#[payload[&quot;empId&quot;]]'" />
            </enricher>
            <choice>
                <when expression="#[flowVars.IDRec.hasNext()]">
                    <logger level="INFO"
                        message="Employee exists, #[payload]" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                   <logger level="INFO" message="Employee does not exist"/>
                </otherwise>
            </choice>
         </flow>
```

However, I get the following error
: Execution of the expression "flowVars.IDRec.hasNext()" failed.

(org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: LinkedHashMap

```
               Type: org.mule.api.MessagingException
               Code  : MULE_ERROR--2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned value is a map. You can try this approach,

```
<choice>
    <when expression="#[flowVars.IDRec.size() > 0]">
        <logger level="INFO" message="Employee exists, #[payload]" />
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <logger level="INFO" message="Employee does not exist"/>
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```